# Why would a variable reset its original value after I assigned a value to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Edit: I accidentally made coor a local variable in the method.

```
using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class Building : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [SerializeField] public int owner;
     [SerializeField] public int tpa, time, level;
     [SerializeField] public double maxHP, HP, atk, def, range, prod, cost;
     [SerializeField] private Vector2 coor;
     [SerializeField] public string type, branch;

     public static double totalprod;
     public static int actions;

     [SerializeField] bool buildStarted = false;
     [SerializeField] bool buildCompleted = false;
     int buildStartedOn;
     bool complete = false;


     public static List<Building> myBuildings = new List<Building>();

     public Vector2 Coor { get => coor;}

     public Building(double hp, int turn_per_action, double attack, double defence, double r, double pro, double c, int t, string typ, int lvl, string bra, int own, Vector2 co)//constructor
     {
         owner = own;
         HP = hp;
         tpa = turn_per_action;
         atk = attack;
         def = defence;
         range = r;
         prod = pro;
         cost = c;
         time = t;
         type = typ;
         level = lvl;
         branch = bra;
         coor = co;


     }
     private void Awake()
     {
         //Building building = new Building(HP, tpa, atk, def, range, prod, cost, time, type, level, branch, owner, coor);
         if(owner == 0)
         {
             myBuildings.Add(this);
         }


     }
     private void Update()
     {
         if(owner == 0)
         {

             if (buildCompleted)
             {

                 if (complete == false)
                 {
                     totalprod += prod;
                     if (type == "Base")
                     {
                         //tpa of base is apt
                         actions += tpa;
                     }
                     Debug.Log(coor);
                     complete = true;
                 }

             }
             else if (buildStarted == false)
             {
                 if (Currency.resource >= cost)
                 {
                     Currency.resource -= cost;
                     BuildDisplay.buildAction--;
                     Vector2 coor = NewBuilding.co;
                     Debug.Log(coor);

                     buildStarted = true;
                     buildStartedOn = Turn.turnCourt;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     MenuManger.Messaging("no resource");
                     Destroy(gameObject);
                 }
             }
         }

         if(buildCompleted == false)
         {
             if(Turn.DeltaT(buildStartedOn) >= time)
             {
                 buildCompleted = true;
             }
         }

         if(HP <= 0)
         {
             Destroy(gameObject);
         }

     }

     public void OnBuilding()
     {
         if (buildCompleted)
         {
             if (SelectAction.isTargeting)
             {
                 if (owner != 0)
                 {
                     Attacking.TargetBuilding = this;
                     Attacking.isAttacking = true;

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     MenuManger.Messaging("invalid target");
                 }
             }
             else if (owner == 0)
             {
                 SelectAction.ActingBuilding = this;
                 MenuManger.ChangeMenu("Action", true);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             MenuManger.Messaging("incomplete building");
         }
     }
     public static List<Building> FindBuildingWithType(string tType)
     {
         var buildings = myBuildings.Where(x => x.type == tType).ToList();

         return buildings;

     }


 }
```

coor is always 0,0 when I look at it from the inspector. 
The only time it is correct is in the Debug.Log() right after the value is assigned. 
That bit of code runs only once. 
I made coor private. 
I used crtl+F to find that this is the only time I changed the value of coor.
I tested other variables and this does not occur.

Comment: its showing the default value, because you have not assigned any value to it

Comment: because you are shadowing it by local variables inside your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
Vector2 coor = NewBuilding.co;
Debug.Log(coor);
```

`coor` is local variable you declared in the scope of your `if (Currency.resource >= cost)` block (and visible only in it) in `Update` method and it is unrelated to `private Vector2 coor;` field (you can check it adding `Debug.Log(this.coor);` after `Debug.Log(coor);` for example). Try changing code to:

```
coor = NewBuilding.co;
Debug.Log(coor);
```